# Understanding Simple Race Condition example

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I'm very new to multithreaded programming and I don't quite understand why exactly I am getting the following outputs in different runs of the [code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)  below.

run 1:

```
http://bar => fake content        
http://foo => fake content
```

run 2:

```
http://bar => fake content
```

run 3:

```
http://foo => fake content
```

I don't quite understand what gets overwritten where?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::map<std::string, std::string> g_pages;

void save_page(const std::string &url)
{
    // simulate a long page fetch
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::string result = "fake content";

    g_pages[url] = result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread t1(save_page, "http://foo");
    std::thread t2(save_page, "http://bar");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    for (const auto &pair : g_pages) {
        std::cout << pair.first << " => " << pair.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your map isn't thread safe. You need a mutex to protect it from the other thread when one of them manipulates it.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your comment. I know that I need a mutex, but I would like to understand what exactly goes wrong where

Comment: Not so easy to say. One thread is partially through changing the map, and then the other thread comes along and does its thing. The map will be left in some inconsistent state, resulting in [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: I see, for example, the first thread is buys traversing the tree to find the right node to insert the element, the second thread kicks in, inserts an element to the tree, the tree gets rebalanced and the first thread continues its traversal but since the tree got rotated it inserts the element at the wrong place?

Comment: Something like that, yeah. It all depends on timing what will happen. Roll the dice :)

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I am just a bit puzzled because the insert is such a fast operation (in such a small map) and it seems to fail quite often in my example, so I must be pretty unlucky to get pre-empted in a critical section all the time

Comment: Nothing with a map is a fast operation.  The nodes are dynamically allocated so every pointer traversed means a cache miss and loading the data from memory at some 200+ cycles.  Maps are not cache friendly at all.